# The word-break style is not applying on text with '$' symbol

Tags: html, css, word-break

The `word-break: break-all;` style is not applying on text with '$' symbol.

---

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>1234567890098765543331234567899766543</span>
    <hr>
    <span>$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$</span>
    <hr>
    <span>etryeuiiosdfghjknmbvcxzxertyuihgtrtyh</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 30px;
}
span{
  display: inline-block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

---

Here is a link: https://jsfiddle.net/kxakpku0/

Comment: This is browser dependant. Chrome will not break the dollars while Firefox will do so (tested with your fiddle).

Comment: Yes @Pharaoh. But it works when i add width on the span [ https://jsfiddle.net/kxakpku0/2/ ]

Comment: not working on the special character with a width property

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer your question (from https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#break-all):

‘break-all’
In addition to ‘normal’ soft wrap opportunities, ***lines may break between any two letters*** (except where forbidden by the ‘line-break’ property). Hyphenation is not applied. This option is used mostly in a context where the text is predominantly using CJK characters with few non-CJK excerpts and it is desired that the text be better distributed on each line.

I've bolded and italicized the appropriate part. On further definition, ***A letter for the purpose of this specification is a character belonging to one of the Letter or Number general categories in Unicode.***

In this case, $ is in the Unicode Character Category 'Symbol, Currency' and thus not a 'Letter', so it will only break at soft break opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

It is `word-wrap: break-word;`

Check out https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp.

Comment: On that link there is only break-word, normal, initial and inherit.

Comment: But op's using `word-break: break-all`, which is valid and should work. I'm asking if you know why that doesn't work and `word-wrap: break-word` does https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#break-all

Comment: oh weird. @mikeg542 gave the explanation.

Comment: And so does break-word when I changed it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Comment: `break-word` is a value of `overflow-wrap`, not of `word-break`.

Comment: Seriously? I thought word-break: break-word; was a chrome notation.
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/word-break/

Comment: Yes, this seems correct (http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break mentions it, too). I only checked W3 and MDN.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in latest MS chrome https://jsfiddle.net/kxakpku0/1/